# NullReferenceException mystery

Tags: .net, visual-studio, exception

For some reason when my application starts up, I get a System.NullReferenceException.  Whats really strange, is how the exception box doesn't point to any line of code.  I have no idea what part is causing the problem.  Here is the stacktrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
 Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
 Source="Microsoft.VisualBasic"
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.MainFormLoadingDone(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at EEMSReports.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Anybody ever see this before or have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What on line 81 of your EEMSReports?

Comment: I ask due to: `at EEMSReports.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81`

Comment: Do you have VS set to break on Common Language Runtime Exceptions?

Comment: Really dumb question, but is there anyway I can turn a setting on that shows me the line numbers?

Comment: @Ragepotato: not exactly sure.  Where is that setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to debug the application when the exception happens, create a project that will launch the application upon starting the debugger (see **Project Properties**->**Debug** tab).  The project need not have any source code.

Afterwards, tell the debugger to break on any thrown exception (see **Debug**->**Exceptions**) and launch your application with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben says in the comments, the null reference is coming from:

EEMSReports.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb : line 81

This indicates a temporary compiler-generated file. From memory, it's possible that this is a bug in the C# compiler, where it deletes the temporary file before trying to use it. But I would set Visual Studio to break on unhandled exceptions, and then see where the exception is thrown.